# Using one Neural Network model inside of ray.pool

Tags: python, machine-learning, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, ray

I am concerned about using Pool() from ray library. This is simplified structure of my question:

```
import torch
import multiprocessing as mp
from ray.util.multiprocessing import Pool

def acquire_data(model,x):
   value = model(x)

model = torch.load('my_model')
workers = mp.cpu_count()
iterations = [i for i in range(100)]
my_pool = Pool(workers) 
data= self_play_pool.map(acquire_data,iterations)
```

My question is will there be any problems when calculating output of model, when model is large Neural Network, because I assume that every process needs to use model to get value, and there is only one model instance, that I have made at the beginning of code. Or am I wrong, does using Pool, makes new model copy for every process, if that is the case how could I optimize this, because copying model would consume a lot of memory and take some time.

I was also thinking about making actor class, where every actor class would have one model, that way I wouldn't need to copy model every time, but I don't think I could parallelize my code than that well. Because if I make 8 actor class objects, I would need to have loop, where every time I would use actor object method to calculate data, but If one method finishes earlier it would need to wait for others, and when using Pool() that is not the case: